# Creating multiple files dynamically and storing different message in each file

Tags: java

```
public static void record(Message  message)//Message is a class 
    {
    try
      {
        BufferedOutputStream buf=new BufferedOutputStream(new      FileOutputStream("E:/kruthika/proj/a.bin"));
        byte[] b =serializer.serialize(message);        
        buf.write(b);
        buf.flush();


      }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.print(e);}
  }
```

this is a small code which serializes my message object(this object contains some text message) and writes it to a binary file. This works perfectly if the object carries only one word for a text but if many words are sent, obviously it is overwritten in the binary file. So how do i alter the snippet to create multiple files dynamically and then store different message in different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either pass the fileName-parameter to the function or use a static counter or the current datetime as filename:
shown is the solution with a counter

```
private static int count = 0;

public static void record(Message  message)//Message is a class 
    {
    try
      {
        BufferedOutputStream buf=new BufferedOutputStream(
          new FileOutputStream("E:/kruthika/proj/" + count + ".bin")
        );
        byte[] b =serializer.serialize(message);        
        buf.write(b);
        buf.flush();

        count++;

      }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.print(e);}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Either pass a file(name) as a method argument

```
 public static void record(Message  message, File binFile)
```

or try to calculate the filename from the message object - maybe it contains the classname?

```
 File binFile = new File("E:/kruthika/proj", createFileName(message));
```

The latter example will store the data in a file with the calculated filename *relative* to the path `E:/kruthika/proj`

Answer (score 1):

```
String filename = "a_" + System.nanotime() + ".bin";
BufferedOutputStream buf=new BufferedOutputStream(new           FileOutputStream("E:/kruthika/proj/" + filename));
    byte[] b =serializer.serialize(message);        
    buf.write(b);
    buf.flush();
    buf.close();
```

is a quick and dirty method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're hard-coding the filename to "E:/kruthika/proj/a.bin", so obviously everything will be written to the same file. If you want different files, don't hard-code the name, e.g. by making it a parameter of the record method.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that claesv?

Comment: take a look at any of the other answers.